# What does come mean

Tags: meaning

Everyone of my friends keeps asking for my come its a verb what do they mean are they dumb!

Please help one tried to hold my hand and they didnt say no homo or any other joke sentences.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

English words can have many meanings, and even be different parts of speech, while retaining the same spelling. Vulgar or slang words are especially common examples of this; many swearwords can be used as just about any part of speech without altering their spelling or pronunciation.

The **verb** "to come" has many many meanings. One of those meanings is "to experience sexual orgasm" or specifically "to ejaculate."

The **noun** "come" refers to the bodily fluid that is a result of ejaculation, *i.e.* semen or female ejaculate.

Sometimes the noun "come" is spelled "cum" instead. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come), citing [Glossophilia](https://www.glossophilia.org/2021/03/the-language-of-sex-come-one-come-all/), says:

> The meaning of *semen* or *female ejaculatory discharge* is considered vulgar slang. Many style guides and editors recommend the spelling *come* for verb uses while strictly allowing the spelling *cum* for the noun. Both spellings are sometimes found in either the noun or verb sense, however. Others prefer to distinguish in formality, using *come* for any formal usage and *cum* only in slang, erotic or pornographic contexts.

(Personally I find "cum" to be incorrect in all cases, but I admit to being a prescriptivist at heart and something of a snob when it comes to language and usage... which is something I ought to change, I suppose.)